# FK_dbo.TimeHoursWorked_dbo.Employee_EmployeeId' is not a constraint. Could not drop constraint. See previous errors

Tags: asp.net

I have suddenly got the following error:

> FK_dbo.TimeHoursWorked_dbo.Employee_EmployeeId' is not a constraint.
>   Could not drop constraint. See previous errors

I dont get it as there are no tables called `dbo.TimeHoursWorked` or `dbo.Employee` (I do have tables `TimeHoursWorked` and `Employee`.

Answer (score 1):

You do actually have tables called

`dbo.TimeHoursWorked` and `dbo.Employee..`

dbo stands for Database Owner, and each table that does not have an owner specified, gets assigned to dbo.

A fully qualified SQL table is

```
<databaseName>.<owner>.<tableName>
```

You can use `SELECT * FROM Employee` which assumes the current database or you can use `SELECT * FROM Payroll.dbo.Employee` which looks in the Payroll database for a table called Employee owned by the database owner

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. So do I have for example two tables, 1 called dbo.Employee and another called Employee  or are they one and the same?

Comment: The answer is, it depends.   You could have two tables with the same name, but a different owner...   However, unless you specifically set the owner, most like dbo.Employee and Employee are the same...